# Multiple intent to broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification

I have a Push-notification app.
I create intent for click on notificaion:

```
Intent open = new Intent();
    open.setAction("com.bupyc.pushall.app.OPEN");
    open.putExtra("url", url);
    open.putExtra("lid", lid);
    open.putExtra("regId", regId);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, open, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

And in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".OpenBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.bupyc.pushall.app.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But if i send more 1 notification intent does not work. Its work only for first notification

If problem with "PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT" how intent multiple broadcast intent with other url, lid extras?

Answer (score 0):

Ok) i found solution :)

```
Intent close = new Intent(this, CloseBroadcastReceiver.class);
    close.setAction("com.bupyc.pushall.app.CANCEL"+NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Its works and for broadcast :)